# JS show attribute name input

Tags: javascript, input

I am trying to run the code on many input tags but it does not work.

If I use a single dial works.

```
function showNameInput () {
    let showName = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name));            
    alert(showName);
});
```

Many input

```
function showName () {
    let showName = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("test").Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input").name));
    showName.forEach((current)=>{        
        alert(current);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach using querySelectorAll to simplify your code:

```js
function showName () {
    let showName = document.querySelectorAll("input.test");
    
    showName.forEach(function(elem){
      alert(elem.name);
    })
}

showName();
```

```html
<input class="test" name="apple"/>
<input class="test" name="orange"/>
<input class="test" name="kiwi"/>
<input class="test" name="banana"/>
```